# What's the best way to pass a common request identifier across a chain of Filter/Services for logging in Finagle/Scala?

Tags: scala, finagle

We use a lot of Finagle `Filter`s and `Service`s in our code. However, we don't support Zipkin in our infrastructure. At times there's a need to *trace* an incoming request across the chain of Filters/Services, especially in the face of concurrent requests. What's the most non-intrusive way to get such a functionality?

**Goal:**
Would be great if Finagle itself provided an additional `apply` method like so:

```
def apply(request: ReqIn, service: Service[ReqOut, RepIn], traceId: String): Future[RepOut]
```

Then the subclasses could opt-in to using this method instead. The last argument being the identifier that every Filter/Service in the chain could "append to".

```
override def apply(request, service, traceId): Future[...] = {
  val myTrace = traceId+".me2" // can be logged if needed
  service.apply(..., myTrace)
}
```

Example:

```
val chain = FilterA andThen FilterB andThen ServiceP

val response = chain(request, UUID.randomString) // need a way to "seed the request chain with unique string"
```

The goal is to have something that can uniquely trace/log the series of filter/services effectively. How may I go about by extending Finagle via traits/monkey-patching? Or is this not doable?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Finagle's [Contexts](https://twitter.github.io/finagle/guide/Contexts.html).

> Contexts give you access to request-scoped state, such as a request’s deadline, throughout the logical life of a request without requiring them to be explicitly passed

Comment: I tried using that but I’m not sure I understand the usage from the link. Do you have another/different example?